# Best practice for serializing different data for a ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a `model` named `Client` that looks like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=50)
    email_address = models.EmailField("Email", max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField("Phone", max_length=15)
```

My app receives data from 2 different sources

**Source A**

```
source_a_data = {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "email_address": "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "phone_number": "5555555555"
}
```

**Source B**

```
source_b_data = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "email1": "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "phone1": "5555555555"
}
```

I know that creating a serializer for **Source A** would look like this:

`serializers.py`

```
class SourceAClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = "__all__"

serializer = SourceAClientSerializer(data=source_a_data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
```

Would it make sense to create a new `ModelSerializer` for source B? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I think you can build a custom middleware to convert camelcase variables to django _ variable. Other solution might be in serializer validation method; before calling super validate method convert camelcase into django _ variables. And if the source B also expect data returned to be in the same format as it sends; then middleware might be best option.

Comment: I definitely appreciate that, but that was just to demonstrate that the data would look different. In reality, the property names are rarely identical. I updated the question to better reflect this.

Comment: use https://github.com/dbrgn/drf-dynamic-fields or https://github.com/AltSchool/dynamic-rest

Comment: Unless I overlooked something, these seem to both be about querying your own data rather than parsing data from external sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify  this as you can use the adapter pattern that will transform all your data sources to a particular format like, this will simplify your validation logic and other things that you may keep changing for example.

```
def adpat_source_b( data ):
   new_data = {}
   new_data["first_name"]  = data["firstName"]
   new_data["last_name"] = data["lastName"]
   new_data["email_address"] = data["email1"]
   new_data["phone_number" ] = data["phone1"]
   return new_data
```

class serializer

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = "__all__"
```

Handling validation error?

For Source A error can be handled without any issue, but for source B the error message/field would require modification, otherwise, client B will see "phone_number" is required even though client A has sent "phone1" to sort out this problem again you can use adapter pattern.

[Adapter Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter)

Comment: The adapter pattern sounds right, I just can't quite picture the correct way to implement it in a way that utilizes the serializer class. With the adapter pattern, is the idea that an independent method 'adapts' the data before it passes the data to the serializer?

Comment: Yes, it will adapt the data before it passes to the serializer.